# Removing an additional Counter from Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

I have created two custom counters `scireq` and `scisubreq` as I'm working on a document specifying requirements and couldn't find any requirements package.

Unfortunately, the requirements come up in the table of contents and I can't figure out how to remove it from the toc. I have tried the `\toclevel@scireq` command to increase toclevel, but to no avail. Setting the `\setcounter{tocdepth}{}` does make changes to Sections, Subsections etc, but the requirements counters always show up.

Is there a setting for counters so they are not included in the toc?

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{chngcntr}



    \titleclass{\scireq}{straight}[\chapter]
    \titleclass{\scisubreq}{straight}[\chapter]
    \newcounter{scireq}
    \newcounter{scisubreq}
    \counterwithin{scisubreq}{scireq}


    \newcommand{\scireqautorefname}{$req_{sci}$}
    \titleformat{\scireq}{\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0em}{$req_{sci}$ \thescireq:~}
    \titlespacing*{\scireq}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

    \newcommand{\scisubreqautorefname}{$req_{sci}$}
    \titleformat{\scisubreq}{\normalsize\bfseries}{}{1.5em}{$req_{sci}$ \thescisubreq:~}
    \titlespacing*{\scisubreq}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

    \newcommand{\reqpar}{\hangafter=0 \hangindent=2em}

    \makeatletter                           
    \providecommand*{\toclevel@scireq}{0}
    \providecommand*{\toclevel@scisubreq}{0}
    \makeatother 



    \begin{document}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Science Requirements}
    \section{Requirements}



    \scireq{Apertures}

        \scisubreq{Minimum Requirement}
        \reqpar{}Requirement Description

        \scisubreq{Target Requirements}
        \reqpar{}Requirement Description\\


    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested a quick work around for this. I have created two new commands which allow using the `\scireq` and `\scisubreq` functions without them appearing in the TOC.

I created `\tscireq` and `\tscisubreq` which increment the counter then call the function with the * option.

```
\newcommand{\tscireq}[2][]{\stepcounter{scireq} \scireq*{#2}}
\newcommand{\tscisubreq}[2][]{\stepcounter{scisubreq} \scisubreq*{#2}}
```

Comment: HELP!!! This workaround means that the requirements do not show in the TOC, but it now means that referencing the requirements no longer works as my labels no longer link!!!